# How to construct multiple MVC in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

It's well known that MVC is the only pattern in iOS. Currently, I'm developing a project with multiple MVCs, I'm confused about organizing these MVCs.

Basically, I have a survey MVC and a Question MVC. The sequence of display for the survey is:

1. An interface for user to key in title and description of survey
2. User clicks next to show the question interface
3. User clicks the next button to show another question interface and so on.

I'm thinking to have one model for the survey and one model for question. But How can I link the survey model to Question as I need an array of question in the survey model, which means the survey model depends on question model?

Please help me on this, thanks so much!

Comment: you need to implement at least one controller handling the information between the models and views.

Comment: your `class survey` can have a `NSArray *questionsArray` instance variable. This questionsArray will be an array of your `class question`. Does this help?

Comment: You might wanna use the singleton pattern. Make the object of `class survey` as singleton, since you have 1 survey which has multiple qns

Comment: It's well known that MVC is the only pattern in iOS. - What???

Comment: @TusharKoul What your are suggesting is an array of MVCs?

Comment: It would help to make a clearer distinction between MVC and individual model, view, or controller objects. @TusharKoul is describing two different *types* of models (survey and question), with the survey model object containing an array of question model objects. Also, as discussed by others here, you will likely end up with multiple *types* of controllers to display various views in your app. MVC is more of an architectural pattern that describes the roles that the objects and classes play here. You don't construct MVC objects or values, you design classes that implement an MVC pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your descreption seems a bit loosy. what you're describing is a Single MVC system where you have multiple views to :

- Display survey.
- Display questions.

and multiple modules to represent :

- Survey object.
- Question object.

you can easily use a `UINavigationController` with two or more `UIViewController`s to build such app.
I suggest you to take a look at apple's [Your second iOS App](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/Introduction/Introduction.html) tutorial which is similar to what you're describing.

Hope that helps